# npm download additional file from unspecified registry

Tags: npm

I am suffering network bandwidth problem. Therefore I setup a proxy registry in my local network at localhost:8081 using nexus. When I do `npm config get`, I can see my registry is properly configured.
However, I do:

```
npm install karma-phantomjs2-launcher@0.1.1
```

I see:

```
> phantomjs2@2.2.0 install /home/liwuwen/temp/rtst/node_modules/phantomjs2
> node install.js                                                                                                            

invalid config loglevel="notice"
PhantomJS not found on PATH                                                                                                  
Downloading https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
Saving to /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2                                                                
Receiving...                                        
  [----------------------------------------] 1% 0.0s
```

And that constantly fails due to the slow network connection. The installation might go through if I
keep trying. But I can not reply on this approach for my development work. Any suggestion about how 
to get npm always use my local registry for the package installation?

Answer (score 0):

In case of `phantomjs2` the npm package itself is downloaded successfully but the package contains an install script which is called with `node install.js` command.
This install tries to download a binary from bitbucket and this fails. 
This step happens not through the local npm registry but it will be tried to download the binary directly.

What you can do about this is to get the binary somehow. (Maybe downloading with a browser.) In the above example, the binary is `phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2`. As it is already downloaded to the local computer its location has to be specified in the environmental variables using `phantomjs` as an environmental variable key. Details about this [can be found here](https://github.com/zeevl/phantomjs2) under the `Downloading from a custom URL` section.

Note that there could be other packages also, that will try to download binary content. Examples for this are the `node-sass` and the `chrome-driver`. They both have a similar trick with an environmental variable as described above with `phantomjs`.